# CSS Prevent text from overflowing the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a description of a website
HTML:

```
<div class="a_desc">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean     commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque 
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque </div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a_desc{
position: relative;
margin: 0.4em auto 0 auto;
background: rgba(27,27,25,0.7);
max-width: 500px;
padding:0.4em;
border-radius: 1em;
font-weight: 100;
max-height: 100%:
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-moz-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
text-size-adjust:100%;
}
.a_desc > div{
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
line-height: 17px;
display: table;
}
.a_desc > div:last-child:after{
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

It works okay on android phone,but when i test it on iphone the text overflows the parent div:
[image: Overflows at the bottom]

How can that be prevented,How can i expand the parent to fit all of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one gave me the right answer, so I kept trying and it turns out that it works if you simply set parent to `display: table;` and child to `display: table-row;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the overflowing text, use:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the overflow:

```
a_desc > div{       
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

And if you don't want to cut of the text, you can add a scroll bar in it with:

```
a_desc > div{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to set the property:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Otherwise, you may use:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

to clip the text vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.a_desc > div{
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
line-height: 17px;
display: table;
height: 100%;
}
```

I also would put the text within p elements for SEO and just give them `display: block` or `inline-block` since this will look the same but would be a bit more neat coding.

Comment: Otherwise give:  .a_desc{ height: auto }

Comment: it's still overflowing

Comment: Can you try with .a_desc{ min-height: 100%; } instead of max

Answer (score 0):

If you want your container to expand/reshape as your window resizes, use the following code:

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

This works for me. When I change window size the container responds to keep the text within.